# How do you bind a complex type containing a list in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

So, I have a model like this:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<EventParticipant> Participants { get; set; }
}

public class EventParticipant
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Strength { get; set; }
    public string Losses { get; set; }

}
```

and I have a form where I have a field for:

1. Title
2. Multiple participants

```
    <form asp-controller="Event" asp-action="Create" method="post">  

        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-controls/>
                                
        <input asp-for="Participants[0].Name" class="form-controls/>                                
        <input asp-for="Participants[0].Strength" class="form-controls/>      
        <input asp-for="Participants[0].Losses" class="form-controls/>    
     
        <input asp-for="Participants[1].Name" class="form-controls/>                                
        <input asp-for="Participants[1].Strength" class="form-controls/>      
        <input asp-for="Participants[1].Losses" class="form-controls/> 
         
        <input type="submit" class="form-controls/>     
    </form>
```

When I go to the page with the above code, I get the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

with the first "Participants" input being highlighted.

How can I make it so that after posting, I can access a list of participants, like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(EventViewModel model)
    {
        foreach (var participant in model.Participants)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + participant.Name);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

Comment: Does your current view add `@model  ventViewModel`? And is there any other code in your view? And what is the code in the action corresponding to the view? Please provide details of these contents, which is related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a contractor to your class:

```cs
public class EventViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<EventParticipant> Participants { get; set; }

  public EventViewModel()
  {
     this.Participants = new List<EventParticipant>();
  }

}
```

this prevents `Participants` null error.

then you can use a `foreach` to access your `EventParticipant` in your views, safely.

Comment: This was sort of it, but then I had to also create 2 EventParticipant objects in my Get Create() function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `asp-for="@Model.Participants[0].Name"`, it will work. Also for binding list dynamically you can try looping over `Model.Participants` like shown below.

For more details refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#expression-names-and-collections

```
<form asp-controller="Event" asp-action="Create" method="post">  

    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-controls/>
                        
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Participants.Count; i++)
    {       
        <input asp-for="@Model.Participants[i].Name" class="form-controls/>                                
        <input asp-for="@Model.Participants[i].Strength" class="form-controls/>      
        <input asp-for="@Model.Participants[i].Losses" class="form-controls/>    
    }
     
    <input type="submit" class="form-controls/>     
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this was one part of it but the key thing was in another answer